# How can you minimize and restore the active window with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want a functionality like when you press 'Win' and 'd' where you see the desktop and if you press it again it restores all windows.

How would one implement that in AHK but with only the active window?

**UPDATE:**

Following code was added, but still unable to restore the minimized window when pressing ALT+s again.

```
!s::
WinGet, active_id, ID, A
if (toggle:=!toggle)
    WinMinimize, ahk_id %active_id%
else
    WinRestore, ahk_id %active_id%
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> shortcut does this, but the functionality somewhat varies depending on what particular window is active. Given a maximized Window, usually using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> shortcut down twice normally does what you want.

So, replacing the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> shortcut w/ 2x <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> looks like this:

```
#d::
Send #{down}
Send #{down}
return
```

**Alternatively, using ahk's built in [WinMinimize](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm) function (Which will probably work better)**:

```
#d::WinMinimize, A
```

**Update: Added the requested restore functionality**

```
Toggle:=0

#d::
Toggle^=1
if(Toggle){
    WinGetTitle, name, A
    WinMinimize, %name%
}
else
    WinRestore, %name%
return
```

**Update 2:**
More reliable hwnd-based version courtesy of a comment by [0x464e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813732/0x464e) <sup>([MWE for hwnd](https://pastebin.com/caSCVUKB))</sup>

```
#d::
    if (toggle:=!toggle)
        WinMinimize, % "ahk_id " _hwnd := WinExist("A")
    else
        WinRestore, % "ahk_id " _hwnd
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force
#NoTrayIcon

MINIMIZED := []
STATE_MINIMIZED := -1

return

; Win + Alt + Down = Minimize Window
#!Down::
{
    global

    for index, winid in MINIMIZED
    {
        if (!WinExist(winid) || WinGetMinMax(winid) != STATE_MINIMIZED)
        {
            MINIMIZED.RemoveAt(index)
        }
    }

    if (hwnd := WinExist("A"))
    {
        winid := "ahk_id " hwnd

        if (WinGetMinMax(winid) != STATE_MINIMIZED)
        {
            PostMessage 0x0112, 0xF020, 0,, winid  ; 0x0112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF020 = SC_MINIMIZE
            MINIMIZED.Push(winid)
        }
    }
}

; Win + Alt + Up = Restore Window
#!Up::
{
    global

    for index, winid in MINIMIZED
    {
        if (!WinExist(winid) || WinGetMinMax(winid) != STATE_MINIMIZED)
        {
            MINIMIZED.RemoveAt(index)
        }
    }

    if (MINIMIZED.Length)
    {
        winid := MINIMIZED.Pop()
        PostMessage 0x0112, 0xF120, 0,, winid  ; 0x0112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF120 = SC_RESTORE
    }
}
```